# Select an anchor near a span/td tag with Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, anchor

Using Python & Selenium, I'd like to reserve a spot through my gym's website for a set time each day. The list of classes offered each day (the number of classes offered vary by day) are in a table. All row elements are either identical or dynamic (cannot be predicted, site is shared with many gyms). Link to reserve class uses an SVG image and 'onclick' event. The only item that is predictable is the row label ('span' tag).

I've managed to locate the unique 'span' tag

```
block = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title="CrossFit: 5:30 PM / Corona"]')
```

I've tried using the found span tag as a starting point (`parent_td = block.find_element_by_xpath("//td")`) but no luck either.

The link I want is two cells to the right from this span tag. If I click on the span title, press TAB twice, and press ENTER (human interacting), I'm able to reserve my spot.

How can I select this anchor tag that is near to the span tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver) 

block.click() #Clicks on the title

actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 2) #Presses the tab key 2 times
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) #Presses the enter key

actions.perform() #Performs these 2 actions sequentially
```

Comment: I was not aware of ActionChains. That is exactly what I needed. Thank you @Sushil !!